# how to fetch the last entry in flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to get the last entry from quickquizlist.html input and get it on test.html. i was tying through app.py but didn't make it, also tried from html page itself but no luck. I'm not an expert but i think my data saved in session and not in sqlalchemy as i though. this is not the problem, i just want to take the last entry from html page and have it on another html page.

the scenario is, when the user fill the text inputs all data (because the user can enter multiple times) will be printed on result.html as a table. i want only the last entry to be printed on test.html

---

here is my app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash, url_for, redirect, session
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import ctypes
import sqlite3
from sqlalchemy import sql, create_engine, select, MetaData, Table
# engine = create_engine("dburl://user:pass@database/schema")
# metadata = MetaData(bind=None)
# table = Table('table_name', metadata, autoload = True, autoload_with = engine)
# stmt = select([table]).where(table.columns.column_name == 'filter')
#
# connection = engine.connect()
# results = connection.execute(stmt).fetchall()


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////Users/AFEER/projects/hello_flask/database.db'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "random string"

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.app = app
# SQLAlchemy.drop_all()
#Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)   # all tables are deleted
# Inserts records into a mapping table
#db.session.add (model object)
# delete records from a table
#db.session.delete (model object)
# retrieves all records (corresponding to SELECT queries) from the table.
#model.query.all ()


#questions table
class quickQuizQuestions(db.Model):
    def __init__(self, TFquestion, TFanswer, MCQquestion, MCQanswer):
        self.TFquestion = TFquestion
        self.TFanswer = TFanswer
        self.MCQquestion = MCQquestion
        self.MCQanswer = MCQanswer
        # obj = quickQuizQuestions()
        # db.session.add(obj)
        # db.session.commit()
        # obj = quickQuizQuestions()
        # db.session.add(obj)
        # db.session.commit()
    id = db.Column('question_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    TFquestion = db.Column(db.String(900))
    TFanswer = db.Column(db.String(1))
    MCQquestion = db.Column(db.String(900))
    MCQanswer = db.Column(db.String(1))

#students answers table
class studentAnswer(db.Model):
    def __init__(self, student_id, student_name, student_answer, postedQuestion):
        self.student_id = student_id
        self.student_name = student_name
        self.student_answer = student_answer
        self.postedQuestion = postedQuestion
        # obj = studentAnswer()
        # db.session.add(obj)
        # db.session.commit()
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # student_id = password
    student_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    student_name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    student_answer = db.Column(db.String(1))
    postedQuestion = db.Column(db.String(900))

    #to render The record set of the student table is sent as a parameter to the HTML template.
    # The server-side code in the template renders the record as an HTML table
@app.route('/result')
def result():
        return render_template('result.html', quickQuizQuestions=quickQuizQuestions.query.all())


@app.route('/')
def Welcome():
    return render_template('Welcome.html')

@app.route('/InstructorLogin')
def InstructorLogin():
    return render_template('InstructorLogin.html')

@app.route('/StudentLogin')
def StudentLogin():
    return render_template('StudentLogin.html')

@app.route('/quickQuizList', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def quickQuizList():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['TFtxtarea'] or request.form['MCQtxtarea']:
            question = quickQuizQuestions(request.form['TFtxtarea'], request.form['TFanswer'], request.form['MCQtxtarea'], request.form['MCQanswer'])
            db.session.add(question)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Record was successfully added')
            return render_template("result.html")
        else:
            flash('Please enter all the fields', 'error')

    return render_template("quickQuizList.html")

@app.route('/StudentPage')
def StudentPage():
    return render_template('StudentPage.html')

@app.route('/test')
def test():
        return render_template('test.html', quickQuizQuestions=db.session.query().select_from(quickQuizQuestions).order_by(quickQuizQuestions.id.desc()).first())
        # obj = session.query(quickQuizQuestions).order_by(quickQuizQuestions.id.desc()).first()
        # flash(obj)
        # return render_template('test.html')

    # return render_template('test.html', quickQuizQuestions=quickQuizQuestions.query.all())


if __name__ =='__main__':
    db.create_all()
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

---

this is my quickquizlist.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tools</title>
<style>

.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #3F3B72;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}
.header-right {
  float: right;
}
.header a.logo {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;

}
.header a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
#buttonClos{
box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #f0f7fa;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #33bdef 5%, #019ad2 100%);
    background-color:#33bdef;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #057fd0;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:7px 18px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 0px #5b6178;display:inline-block;

}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #FFFAFA;
}

.form{padding:20px;
font-size:20px;
}
</style>
    <script>
function quickQuiz() {

        var questionType = document.getElementById("questionType").value;

<!--        TF elements-->
        var TFtxtarea = document.getElementById("TFtxtarea");
        var label1 = document.getElementById("label1");
        var TFanswer = document.getElementById("TFanswer");
        var TFsubmit = document.getElementById("TFsubmit");

<!--        MCQ elements-->
        var MCQtxtarea = document.getElementById("MCQtxtarea");
        var a = document.getElementById("a");
        var b = document.getElementById("b");
        var c = document.getElementById("c");
        var txta = document.getElementById("txta");
        var txtb = document.getElementById("txtb");
        var txtc = document.getElementById("txtc");
        var MCQsubmit = document.getElementById("MCQsubmit");
        var label2 = document.getElementById("label2");
        var MCQanswer = document.getElementById("MCQanswer");

        if(questionType == "TF" || questionType == "tf")
        {
            TFtxtarea.style.display="block";
            label1.style.display="block";
            TFanswer.style.display="block";
            TFsubmit.style.display="block";

            MCQtxtarea.style.display="none";
            a.style.display="none";
            b.style.display="none";
            c.style.display="none";
            txta.style.display="none";
            txtb.style.display="none";
            txtc.style.display="none";
            MCQsubmit.style.display="none";
            label2.style.display="none";
            MCQanswer.style.display="none";
        }

        if(questionType == "MCQ" || questionType == "mcq")
        {
            MCQtxtarea.style.display="block";
            a.style.display="block";
            b.style.display="block";
            c.style.display="block";
            txta.style.display="block";
            txtb.style.display="block";
            txtc.style.display="block";
            MCQsubmit.style.display="block";
            label2.style.display="block";
            MCQanswer.style.display="block";

            TFtxtarea.style.display="none";
            label1.style.display="none";
            TFanswer.style.display="none";
            TFsubmit.style.display="none";
        }
  }
</script>
</head>
{%- for category, message in get_flashed_messages(with_categories = true) %}
         <div class = "alert alert-danger">
            {{ message }}
         </div>
      {%- endfor %}
<div class="header">
    <a class="logo">QuickQuiz</a>

</div>
<form action = "{{ request.path }}" method = "POST">
<div  class="form">
   <p> Enter the question type (TF/MCQ):</p>
    <input type="text" id="questionType" placeholder="TF or MCQ:">
    <br><br>
<label style="border:inset" id="submitQuestionType" onclick="quickQuiz()"> Submit</label>
    <br><br>

    <textarea name="TFtxtarea" id="TFtxtarea" style="display:none" placeholder="Type your TF question here"></textarea>
    <br><br>
    <label style="display:none" id="label1">Enter the correct answer:</label>
    <input style="display:none" type="text" id="TFanswer" name="TFanswer">
    <br>
    <input style="display:none" id="TFsubmit" type = "submit" value = "Submit & Post" />

    <textarea name="MCQtxtarea" id="MCQtxtarea" style="display:none" placeholder="Type your MCQ question here"></textarea>
    <br>
    <label id="a" style="display:none">Option A</label>
    <input type="text" id="txta" style="display:none"> <br>
    <label id="b" style="display:none">Option B</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtb" style="display:none"> <br>
    <label id="c" style="display:none">Option C</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtc" style="display:none">

    <br>
    <label id="label2" style="display:none">Enter the correct answer</label>
    <input type="text" id="MCQanswer" name="MCQanswer" style="display:none">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" id="MCQsubmit" style="display:none" value="Submit & Post">

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

this is the result.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
   <head>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/linways/table-to-excel@v1.0.4/dist/tableToExcel.js"></script>
<script>
function exportReportToExcel() {
  let table = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
  TableToExcel.convert(table[0], {
    name: `Questions & Answers.xlsx`,
    sheet: {
      name: 'Sheet 1'
    }
  });
}

</script>
   </head>
   <body style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #FFFAFA;">
<div   style="width:800px; margin:0 auto;">
      <h3>
         <a style="color:#14568B;" href = "{{ url_for('result') }}"> Click to Show Table of Questions and Answers</a>
      </h3>

      <hr/>
      {%- for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
         {{ message }}
      {%- endfor %}

      <h3> (<a style="color:#14568B;" href = "{{ url_for('quickQuizList') }}">Click to Add Quick Quiz Question
         </a>)</h3>

      <table style="border: 1px solid black;">
         <thead>
            <tr width="380" style="border: 20px solid black ;">
               <th width="80" style="border: 1px solid black ;">TF Question</th>
               <th width="80" style="border: 1px solid black ;">TF Answer</th>
               <th width="80" style="border: 1px solid black ;">MCQ Question</th>
               <th width="80" style="border: 1px solid black ;">MCQ Answer</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>

         <tbody>
            {% for question in quickQuizQuestions %}
               <tr style="border: 1px solid black;">
                  <td style="border: 1px solid black;">{{ question.TFquestion }}</td>
                  <td style="border: 1px solid black;">{{ question.TFanswer }}</td>
                  <td style="border: 1px solid black;">{{ question.MCQquestion }}</td>
                  <td style="border: 1px solid black;">{{ question.MCQanswer }}</td>
               </tr>
            {% endfor %}
         </tbody>
      </table>
<br>
      <br>
<button id="btnExport" onclick="exportReportToExcel(this)">Download Report</button>
   </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

---

this is test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Answer The Following Question</h1>
<form method="POST">
<label id="questionLabel" ></label>


    <p>
<!--        <label>{{ quickQuizQuestions|length }} HERE!</label>-->
        <label>
<!--              {% for question in quickQuizQuestions %}-->
<!--              {% if loop.lenght == quickQuizQuestions|length %}-->

<!--              {% endif %}-->
<!--            {% endfor %}-->
<!--                        {{quickQuizQuestions|string}} HERE-->
                test
        </label>
    </p>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are retrieving all objects from the database using `quickQuizQuestions.query.all()`.

You want to retrieve only one object; your last entry. If your question id does increment, you can do this with:

```
quickQuizQuestions.query.order_by(-quickQuizQuestions.id).limit(1).all()
```

or

```
quickQuizQuestions.query.order_by(-quickQuizQuestions.id).first()
```

to directly retrieve it.

Comment: Thanks!!! i was confused because i am no friend with python!!! i saccutally did this and it worked.return render_template('test.html', quickQuizQuestions=quickQuizQuestions.query.order_by(-quickQuizQuestions.id).limit(1).all())

Comment: can i do if stmnt like if TF question then provide TF question with its html elements. if MCQ question then provide MCQ question with its html elements? I am thinking using if request.form[] but no idea how to reach html elements from another html file...